# Make the half circle more elliptic

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

This is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/c4upM/103/

I have the gray arc and the blue/green arc.

I am trying to make them more Elliptic, like:

[image]

and I didn't succeed.

I read this one: http://jsbin.com/ovuret/2/edit and tried to make it on my jsfiddle but I didn't succeed because the arc-s are painted in the function of: `DrawCircle` and `DrawEllipseForProjection`.
There are two functions: `blueArc` and `grayarc`. by the `radian angle`, there is a calculation in function `circleInArc` that places the small lightblue circle and the small gray circle (when you mouse over the canvas) in the arc-s.

I want these functions to work after the change but I didn't succeed.

these are the blue and gray arc-s:

```
function grayArc(strokeColor, cx, cy, radius, ctx, linewidth) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, Math.PI, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.lineWidth = linewidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    ctx.stroke();
}

function blueArc(strokeColor, radianStart, radianEnd, cx, cy, radius, ctx, linewidth) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, radianStart, radianEnd);
    ctx.lineWidth = linewidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

and this is the `circleInArc` function:

```
function circleInArc(fillColor, radianAngle, cx, cy, radius, ctx, linewidth) {
    var x = cx + radius * Math.cos(radianAngle);
    var y = cy + radius * Math.sin(radianAngle);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, linewidth / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
    ctx.fill();
    return ({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        radius: linewidth / 2
    });
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try draw arc with bigger radius and not from Math.PI to 2*Math.PI but this one

```
ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, Math.PI*5/4, Math.PI * 7/4);
```

and don't forget move the arc down for radius size

```
grayArc("rgb(177,177,177)", cx, cy+radius, radius*2, ctx, linewidth);
```

hope it will help

Answer (score 2):

I've fiddled around a bit, and you'll propably have to adjust some of the values, but here's an example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4upM/105/) (Only the gray arc was adjusted)

The basic strategy is to save the state of the context, then scale it to your liking. If you only scale one axis.. voilá, ellipsis.

Also, I translated the origin of the canvas to the center of the arc before scaling, because they get scewed with the scaling. The center of the arc is then `0, 0`.

After that the context can be restored like nothing ever happened, an you can stroke your transformed arc.

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(cx,cy);
ctx.scale(1.3, 1);
ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 1.2*Math.PI, 1.8*Math.PI);
ctx.restore();
```

You'll propably want to play around with the radius, the ratio of scaling and maybe the range in which the arc gets drawn to fit your needs.

**Edit:** I cut down on the range of the arc which gets drawn, to prevent the stubby ends of the ellipsis showing. From `1.2*PI` to `1.8*PI` instead of `1*PI to 2*PI` seems to look alright in the current case. :)

For future questions, please try to extract the a more basic example of your problem, to make it easier for those who want to help out. :)